# System in C++ Wall Clock Time

Tags: c++, bash, system

I am trying to run a bash nvme flush command from a C++ program with a timer having been started. This is to allow an nvme driver to complete all writing to drive before taking the second timestamp and performing a time calculation. My question is whether the bash instructions specified in a C++ system() command will execute before the next line of the C++ program.

```
fd = open (fname.c_str (), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0660);

// Verify the file has been opened.
if (fd == -1)
{
    cout << get_datetime_string() << "Write open of " << fname 
    << " failed.  Errno: " << errno << endl;
}
else
{
    // Total bytes written.
    uint64_t written = 0;

    // Notify the start of the test.
    cout << get_datetime_string() << "Write test started" << endl;

    // Elapsed time.
    struct timeval tv = { 0 };
    get_elapsed_time (&tv);
    struct timeval write_tv = tv;

    // Run until it is time for the test to stop.
    while (written < READ_LIMIT && zero_writes < 10)
    {
        ssize_t writesize = write (fd, &buf[0], blocksize);
        if (writesize == -1)
        {
            cout << get_datetime_string << "Write failure.  Errno: " << errno << endl;
            zero_writes = 10;
        }
        else if (0 == writesize)
        {
            cout << get_datetime_string() << "Zero bytes written" << endl;
            zero_writes++;
        }
        else
        {
            written += writesize;
        }
    }

//
// ISSUE THE NVME FLUSH COMMAND HERE
// Something like system("nvme flush...");
//


// Get the elapsed time.
get_elapsed_time (&write_tv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `system` waits for the command to exit.

Otherwise it could not give you the program's return value as it does on some systems. On POSIX systems you can use `WEXITSTATUS` to retrieve this, so the command must have finished.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

If your machine has `man` and the appropriate documentation installed, you can use `man 3 system` to find out how system behaves on your machine:

For example [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) it says that "system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and *returns after the command has been completed*. "